# Can valgrind output partial reports without having to quit the profiled application?

Tags: valgrind

I want to check a long running process for memory leaks with valgrind. I suspect the memory leak I'm after might happen only after several hours of execution. I can run the app under valgrind and get the valgrind log just fine, but doing so means I have to quit the application and start it again anew for a new valgrind session for which I would still have to wait several hours. Is it possible to keep valgrind and the app running and still get valgrind's (partial) data at any point during execution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that by using the [Valgrind gdbserver and GDB](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver).

In short, you start your program with valgrind as usual, but with the `--vgdb=yes` switch:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --vgdb=yes ./a.out
```

In another session, you start gdb on the same executable, and connect to valgrind. You can then issue valgrind commands:

```
$ gdb ./a.out
...
(gdb) target remote | vgdb
....
(gdb) monitor leak_check full reachable any
==8677== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==8677==    at 0x4C28E3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==8677==    by 0x400591: foo (in /home/me/tmp/a.out)
==8677==    by 0x4005A7: main (in /home/me/tmp/a.out)
==8677== 
==8677== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==8677==    at 0x4C28E3D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==8677==    by 0x400591: foo (in /home/me/tmp/a.out)
==8677==    by 0x4005AC: main (in /home/me/tmp/a.out)
==8677== 
==8677== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8677==    definitely lost: 64 bytes in 2 blocks
==8677==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8677==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8677==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8677==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8677== 
(gdb)
```

See the manual for a list of commands, [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands) for memcheck.

Comment: What if I want to do this as part of a Jenkins build?