# valgrind on infinite loop

Tags: c, valgrind, infinite-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can valgrind output partial reports without having to quit the profiled application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720632/can-valgrind-output-partial-reports-without-having-to-quit-the-profiled-applicat)

Can we use valgind on an infinite loop?

As valgrind tools display results after the program exits. Is there any tool or a way to get valgrind working on a program with infinite loop.

As an example:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i=0;

    while(1)
    {
        int *ptr=malloc(10*sizeof(int));        
    }

}
```

how will i check the memory leaks like this?

This program will never end. So can i generate any repot while the program is running?

Comment: Probably not, as it doesn't check for un-referenced data, just data that is left on the heap after the program exist (as it's technically possible to free that data later).

Comment: yes exactly we can free the data later. But there should be a run time parameter which could generate the report from time to time in a file about all the allocated memory at that time.
this thing can be really handy

Comment: Ehm, are you suggesting adding additional functionality to valgrind here? I'm not sure this is the place for that. Try http://valgrind.org/

Comment: i was just asking if anyone knows if valgrind has any such functionality?